# What happens when you transform the test set using MinMaxScaler

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

i am currently in the process of pre-processing my data and I understand that i have to use the same scaling parameters I have used on my training set, on my test set. However, when i applied the `transform` method from `sklearn` library, i noticed something weird.

I first used `preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))` on my training set which sets the maximum to be 1 and minimum to be 0. Next, i used `minmax_scaler.transform(data)` on my test set and I've noticed when i printed out the data-frame, I have values that are greater than 1. What can this possibly mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given feature `x`, your `minmax` scaling to `(0,1)` will effectively map:

`x to (x- min_train_x)/(max_train_x - min_train_x)`

where `min_train_x` and `max_train_x` are the minimum and maximum value of `x` in the **training set**.

If a value of `x` in the **testing set** is larger than the `max_train_x` the scaling transformation will return a value `> 1`.

It usually is not a big problem except if the input has to be in the `(0,1)` range.

Comment: So if the value is >1 will it be considered as an anomaly in my model and disregarded completely?

Comment: What model are we talking about? Most models would treat is as an outlier at worse. I would kind of expect the model to perform poorly on rows with entries outside the range is was trained on, but nothing too bad here.

Answer (score 0):

Actually MinMaxScalar is used when you want you data to be in specific range. for example if you have data like

this is 2d Array

```
[
[1000,2000],
[3000,4000],
[1,2],
[3,50]
]
```

now in this data I want that minimum number will be 1 and maximum number will be 100
so I have to convert all the data into range (1,100)

Now My data will become

```
[
[ 33.97799266,50.47523762],
[100,100],
[1,1],
[1.06602201,2.1885943 ]
]
```

MinMax Scaler In python

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
data = [[1000,2000],[3000,4000],[1,2],[3,50]]
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(1, 100))
print(scaler.fit(data))
print(scaler.transform(data))
```